# Can the resolution algorithm be applied to any FOL formula?

Tags: first-order-logic, programming, automated-theorem-proving

I have been searching for an automatic method (a computer program) to evaluate any first-order logic (FOL) formula given some knowledge base. The most common approach to do this is to use PROLOG. The issue with PROLOG is that it employs a subset of FOL which, for example, restricts the use of quantifiers.

When searching about this, I have learned that PROLOG uses the **resolution algorithm**, which requires formulae to be in **Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF)**. I have also learned that there is a process called **Skolemnization** that can be used to remove the quantifiers from a formula and help convert it into CNF.

Therefore, my question is the following: **Can the resolution algorithm be applied to any FOL formula?** By this, I mean if there exists some algorithm that takes as input **any** FOL formula and normalizes it (using skolemnization and other methods) into CNF so that resolution can be applied to it?